# Freemarker template engine <#if condition> with dynamic condition

Tags: java, templates, freemarker, apache-spark

I am using Spark framework with Freemarker templating engine. I pass a list of category (a Java class that has getId() method) to my template.

In my Freemarker template, I have the following loop, and I only need to show the category title when its id is greater than 1. However, for some unknown reason, the following code does not work unless I remove the <#if condition> part.

```
<#list categories as category>
   <#if category.getId() > 1> category.getTitle() </#if>
</#list>
```

I am wondering if freemarker ever supports this kind of dynamic <#if> statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the greater-than sign is seen as the end of the `#if` tag. So in effect you have `<#if category.getId()>` there, and the id is not a boolean. Try `<#if (category.getId() > 1)>`. (And BTW, just write `category.id`. No need for `get...()`-s in FreeMarker.)